# DocumentSnapshot has data but all fields are null Flutter (from Firestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving data from FutureBuilder, but all fields are null:

```
    Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> artistaTMP;

    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        artistaTMP = widget.database.getFutureArtistById(widget.name);
      }

    FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            future: artistaTMP,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                Artista artistaTrovato =
                Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot.data);
                print(artistaTrovato.toString());
                .
                .
                .
```

This is the function invoked in `initState`:

```
    Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getFutureArtistById(
          String id) async {
        return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("ids")
            .doc("tabs")
            .collection(id[0])
            .doc(id)
            .get();
      }
```

This is `fromDocument`:

```
    factory Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot(
          DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
        return Artista(
          regione: doc.data()["regione"],
          citta: doc.data()["citta"],
          comune: doc.data()["comune"],
          nome: doc.data()["nome"],
          settore: doc.data()["settore"],
          lavoro: doc.data()["lavoro"],
          progetti: doc.data()["progetti"],
          id: doc.data()['id'],
          posts: doc.data()["posts"],
        );
      }
```

These are the prints :

```
    flutter: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
    flutter: null/null/null/null/null/null/progetti:null/
```

I receive data from `Firestore` since `hasData` is true, but all fields are null when I read it.

What I think is that I'm not reading in the right way from `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Are you sure that the document exists? `hasData` can return true even if the document is not found. You need to check `snapshot.exists` is true.

Comment: Uuuh, you're right. I'll check and let you know